# Getting selected option from object bound list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

The catch is that we don't want to use 2 way binding. we have component set like this:

```
<select type="text" formControlName="region" (change)="regionChanged($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let region of regionsDDL" [ngValue]="region">{{region.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

form is build as reactive one using form builder:

```
this.fb.group({
.
region:...
.
});
```

What i want to get in event handler is the whole object bound to selected option. Is it safe just to access form group value like this:

```
regionChanged($event) {
    let selectedRegion = this.basicInfoForm.controls["region"].value;
      }
```

or is it not guaranteed that form control value update happens before (change) event occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a `ngModel` to it and use `ngModelChange()` event

```
<select type="text" formControlName="region" [ngModel]="someValue" (ngModelChange)="regionChanged($event)">
              <option *ngFor="let region of regionsDDL" [ngValue]="region">{{region.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: huh man, that's directly what i needed. could you please point me somewhere in docs where i could have found that myself? i've spent fair amount of time looking for it and couldn't. thanks!

Comment: @deezg Refer this [**github link**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4843)

Comment: @deezg Cool. happy helping you. let me know if you need more help via fb @ aravind2109.. :)